# How to execute a SQL file using MySQL command line tool?

Tags: mysql, sql, command-prompt

I'm using symfony, putty and other SQL commands seem to work fine but when I try to run an `.sql` file (of which there are many), the command line throws an error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual ...
```

This is the command I'm trying to execute:

```
mysql < data/MySQLFile.sql;
```

I already used the `use` command on the proper database and tried using the full path, relative path, etc. Not sure what the problem is.

Here's the statement:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
    ADD COLUMN `blahblah` varchar(10) NULL;
ALTER TABLE tablename
    ADD COLUMN `ggggggg` varchar(50) NULL;
```

Comment: What about showing us the SQL statement that generates the error? We can't see the SQL file from here.

Comment: Yeah I posted the sql statement that generates the error it's `mysql < data/MySQLFile.sql;`

Comment: No. That's not the statement. The statement that generates the error is somewhere *in* that SQL script.

Comment: Oh okay I'll edit the original post to include it.

Comment: The error message should tell you exactly which line of the file failed, and which part of the line had the problem. For example: `ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 17 in file: 'MySQLFile.sql': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '--I tried to do a comment but forgot the space after the dashes' at line 1`

Comment: Those two lines seem correct to me. Does that work when you run them standalone? Did you maybe forget a `;` in the statement right before them?

Comment: Can you add the structure of `tablename` ?

Comment: Can I downvote the upvoter?

Answer (score 12):

if you want to execute through command line

`mysql -u user -p < file.sql`

and if you want to execute once logged in to mysql database. use any of the below commands.

```
source file.sql
```

or

`\. file.sql`

or

```
mysql db_name <file.sql
```

Comment: After hours of searching this `source file.sql` was what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Ok if you are in the mysql interface already type in:

```
\. /full path/to/file.sql
```

What I meant with full path is that you need to specify according to the current OS file system the location of the file. Just by putting data/ is not enough. For example if you are using MAC OS it would be:
From the terminal and assuming is in Documents:

```
mysql < /Users/<yourusername>/Documents/file.sql
```

If you are already logged in mysql then type in:

```
\. /Users/<yourusername>/Documents/file.sql
```

If my tips don't help you, I will recommend you to go to this page:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-batch-commands.html
To Find out more about this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to type 'source' before the path to the sql file. So you would have

```
mysql < source [fullpath]/MySQLFile.sql;
```